# Can't find parameter on querystring

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a query string in which the parameter want this between apostrophes :

```
select * from myTable t
where t.name= ':name'
```

However when debugging the code he tells me not find the parameter :

```
protected bool validName(string n, NHibernate.ISession sesion){


var result= sesion.CreateSQLQuery(Queries.getQuery("queryName"))
                .SetParameter("name", n)
                .UniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Query parser should apply the sql statements for your. Try doing your query like this:

```
select * from myTable t where t.name = :name
```

I would recommend you using `HQL`, for sample:

```
var result = session.CreateQuery("from Entity t where t.name = :name")
                    .SetParameter("name", n)
                    .UniqueResult();
```

Where `Entity` is the entity that references your table (by mapping).

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes are used to indicate a literal string. They should and can not be used around parameter names.